# How do I get the class of a object within a Django template?

Tags: django

If I have a list of objects that require similar layouts but need some attribute set based on the class of object how can I go about getting the class name while **class** and other **xx** values are not available within templates.

```
{% for obj in objects %}
 <div class={{obj.__class__.__name__}}
   ..
 </div>
{% endfor }}
```

There is probably an alternative approach i'm missing here..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A little dirty solution

If objects is a QuerySet that belong to a model, you can add a custom method to your model.

```
 class mymodel(models.Model):
     foo = models........


 def get_cname(self):
    class_name = ....
    return class_name
```

then in your template you can try:

```
{% for obj in objects %}
   <div class="{{obj.get_cname}}">
     ..
  </div>
{% endfor }}
```

Answer (score 39):

You can also write a custom filter. My [use case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14291933/1123985) was to check whether or not an html element in a Django form was a checkbox. This code has been tested with Django 1.4.

I followed the instructions about [Custom Filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters). My filter code looks as such.

In `myapp/templatetags/class_tag.py`:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.filter(name='get_class')
def get_class(value):
  return value.__class__.__name__
```

In your template file:

```
{% load class_tag %}

{% if Object|get_class == 'AClassName' %}
 do something
{% endif %}


{{ Object|get_class }}
```

Comment: this is a better solution

Comment: This is the most Djangoesque solution.

Comment: great; just don't forget to restart your server after creating the templatetag, otherwise you'll get an error.

Answer (score 2):

a bit simpler; assuming your layout is a list of a single model:

```
class ObjectListView(ListView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'object_list.html'

    def model_name(self):
        return self.model._meta.verbose_name
```

Then in `object_list.html`:

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
    <div class="{{view.model_name}}">...</div>
{% endfor }}
```

Answer (score 0):

David's suggestion of a custom filter is great if you need this for several classes.

The Django docs neglect to mention that the dev server won't detect new templatetags automatically, however, so until I restarted it by hand I was stuck with a `TemplateSyntaxError class_tag is not a registered tag library`.

.