# How to detect type of form element in Django template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm working on rendering a form template. The relevant code is something like this:

```
{% for field in filter.form %}
  {% if field.is_hidden %}
    {{ field }}
  {% else %}
    <div class="field">
        {{ field }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

So far, so good. If it's a hidden field, just display the field. If not, put a div wrapper with the class `field` to activate some CSS from the framework I'm using.

However, I need that class in the div wrapper to be `picker` if the field is a select box. It needs to be `picker-multiple` if it's a select multiple box. And so on.

Is this possible to do in the template view? We're working with a framework (which is why I don't want to just target the form fields differently with CSS), but we'd like the core code to work without the framework (which, I think, is why we wouldn't want to do this sort of thing in the separate Python file).

As for what I've tried, I noticed that `{{ field.field.widget }}` renders something like `<django.forms.widgets.Select object at 0x10d822a50>`. I would have then expected `{{ field.field.widget.Select }}` to render *something* (`True` came to mind), but it does nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get type of Django form widget from within template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809874/get-type-of-django-form-widget-from-within-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks) includes field_type and widget_type template filters for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to use a custom template tag as detailed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927018/django-how-to-check-if-field-widget-is-checkbox-in-the-template) explains a similar issue with a solution using custom template tag.